# I've created a React project, when I download packets, I encountered the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

./src/App.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-8-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-8-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-8-4!./src/App.less)
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "demo_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "antd": "^4.15.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8"
  }
}
```

```
// config-overrides.js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    fixBabelImports('import', {
        libraryName: 'antd',
        libraryDirectory: 'es',
        style: true
    }),
    addLessLoader({
        lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            modifyVars: {}
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete your node_modules folder from the project and run this command npm install then run your project